# How to keep the nav active bg color to stay active when on a page?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `rails 4.0.1` with `ruby 2.0.0` and the latest `bootstrap.`

I have a navbar with nav links that lead to a different page such as Home, About Us, Contact, etc.

I got the default navbar hover link bg color to change but I can't seem to keep the background color of the link to stay that color when I actually click on the link and go to that page.

Here's the code:

CSS:

```
$navbar-default-bg: #9B242D;
$navbar-default-link-color: white;
$navbar-default-link-hover-bg: #BC3F49;
$navbar-default-link-active-bg: #BC3F49;
$navbar-default-link-active-color: white;
```

the _header.html.erb

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-links navbar-default">

      <li><%= link_to "About Us", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Our Mission", mission_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "The Founders", founder_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Current Events", current_events_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Donations", donations_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>

    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add class `active` to  `<li>` when u are on that page, to do this

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(about_path) %>"><%= link_to "About Us", about_path %></li>
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(mission_path) %>"><%= link_to "Our Mission", mission_path %></li>
```

and so on.

Comment: This did not work :( I have this navbar as a partial page that renders automatically on all pages. Idk if that information helps but yeah I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind this worked after I changed 'active-bg' to just 'active'!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using javascript to add a class of "current-page" which will adjust the background colour of the aforementioned link. This will involve adding classes to your all your *< li >* to identify them and you can use something like

```
 window.location
```

to get the current URL the page is on. e.g.

```
<li class="js-contact"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
```

The active link classes are more for intra-page tabbing.